Ventilation and insulation for a wooden floor in a tenement house (renovation)
I have an apartment with a wooden floor in a tenement house.
Construction: wooden joists, the neighbor's ceiling boards attached to them from below, then air up to the "blind ceiling", then plaster there, boards for the joists and parquet.
What I replaced: I removed the damaged parquet floor and the boards partially eaten by woodworms. I treated everything with insect repellent and strengthened the joists (especially near the windows where there was probably moisture and the bark beetle entered more easily).
I put some mineral wool on the blind ceiling to bring some relief to the downstairs neighbor (leaving a gap to the boards for ventilation).
I replaced the poppa with expanded clay where it needed to be selected. However, I am wondering whether to pour it down to the level (instead of boards, I will nail 25mm OSB to the joists and new panels on top of it), or leave a ventilation gap?
It wasn't there with the plaster, but the old boards and parquet had natural gaps, OSB and modern panels do not leave such gaps. Perhaps such an air tunnel would be advisable over the expanded clay and before the OSB?
What problem do I see that then the board will sit only on the joists and new supports, and not the entire surface on the expanded clay (always additional stiffening, although it is 25mm OSB so it is rather difficult to bend).
And if you make these "channels" for ventilation - how to finish them? Take it out somewhere near the wall, leave a gap like an expansion joint?

Some pictures would help explain what you've done & what you're trying to do. You start out talking about a ceiling, then switch to talking about a floor. Are you repairing the ceiling surface of a lower apartment, or the floor surface of an upper apartment? Are you the owner? Where in the world are you? In many jurisdictions, working on a rental without proper credentials is illegal...

Sorry for wrong wording, it's about my floor. Yes, I am the owner.
